# Disk and CPU always 100% on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, mbr

I have a dual-boot Windows 10 and Windows 8.1. I actually installed Windows 10 to play games, but it seems like disk and CPU usage is almost full. I have tried to optimize it, but it just doesn't seem to work. New driver updates were the only thing that I actually did, since there were no applications that were consuming my CPU. Games that I play don't run smooth, but it works just fine on windows 8.1, the OS that I use for work. I'll edit this post and put up some links, since I don't have much reputation, as I am now at work and booting literally takes a whole minute, as it loads up the boot manager of windows 8.1 and then restart, and then it arrives at the windows 10 login screen. Here are some specs of my PC:

> Manufacturer: Dell

---

> Model: Latitude E5440

---

> RAM: 4 GB

---

> Processor: Intel Core i5-4300U CPU

---

> Cores: 2

I think this problem might originate from windows 10 bugs, but I am not entirely sure. My PC runs on legacy, MBR table, and I had recently changed it from UEFI GPT table to MBR, Legacy boot.

Any suggestions are accepted.

Thanks.

EDIT: I had one user post down his thoughts on narrowing the question, so here are some more details:

- Windows 10 would always run slow, let's forget about the boot time for now.
- Well, programs open up fast, but they **do not** run smooth.
- I had just installed Windows 10, after formatting my PC and along with it, Windows 8.1
- Well, I am currently booted up in Windows 8.1, I'll answer this question after sometime
- When running windows 10, it definitely does not run hot.
- The ROM is actually a HDD, the laptops back in 2015, or something, and I have installed it on the HDD, by giving it a decent amount of space.
- I know the fact that my Windows 10 has the latest update: 20H2
- I'll see about the other question, after sometime.

EDIT2: This is a link for the usages:
https://prnt.sc/voi4x4

EDIT3: Well, it might seem like the problem of the windows module installer worker, which takes care of updating windows. If you guys require the clock speeds, here it is:

https://prnt.sc/vpjjd2

So, here is the troubleshooting message:

https://prnt.sc/vpjtfg

https://prnt.sc/vpjtow

https://prnt.sc/vpju5i

This is the Task Manager screenshot: https://prnt.sc/vpjvsj

Thanks.

Comment: Considering that the Disk is your maxed out metric, it would've been nice if the screenshot was sorted by that column rather than memory, however it looks like wsappx is using the most of your disk, see: https://fossbytes.com/wsappx-process-100-disk-usage-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk usage should ideally, with a computer doing nothing than having Task Manager open, be 0% or very near to 0%.

With Windows 10, so many things are going on in the background and you need to approach them one by one.

1. Open Task Manger, sort by the column that is maxed out.
2. Research (Google or whatever you use) the name of the application using all of your resources, find out if this is a known issue with an acceptable solution. (Common issues arise from Windows Super Search, Microsoft Store updates, and sometimes a Windows Update can do this while it is installing.)
3. Assess the solution (disabling the wsappx from your screenshot will stop your Microsoft Store updates - determine if this is important to you) and apply them one-by-one until your computer seems to be normal.
4. Once your metrics are normal (0% disk, low CPU and low Memory when nothing is running but Task Manager), run performance tests to determine your laptop's baseline.
   https://www.userbenchmark.com/ is great as it offers free benchmarks for CPU, RAM, GPU, Storage Drive, etc. and compares to other users' data.
5. Record these metrics, and in your case run them again in your Win8 boot and hopefully the numbers will be similar.
6. Understand that your computer has a 4th generation i5 processor (most current is 11th gen, so 7 years of progress) and only 4GB of RAM, and it isn't a gaming laptop. If your Win8 boot runs the game fine then expecting the same performance out of the Win10 boot is fair, just be reasonable with your expectations.

Comment: The game is actually a browser game (Downloadable), and it just works fine in windows 8.1, but not very much in windows 10, but well, Windows 10 should just give a fair amount of performance. Also, fiddling with the game mode in Win10 (Which is on by default), does make my laptop, a little laggy. But anyways, Thanks!

Comment: In my experience with 100% disk, there's a few ways to go about fixing it. Either end the process that's using the disk and prevent it from ever running again, or you can just let the PC stay on and run for a few solid days, like a good 72 hours or more and by then the process might be done reading/writing and you can return to normal. If your game runs fine on Win8, then you should definitely be able to get the same out of Win10, and personally I notice that Win10 is infinitely better on a good SSD. If you're comfortable upgrading, consider buying an SSD.

Comment: An M.2 NVMe SSD is your best option if your Laptop has an M.2 slot.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific about what types of things run "slow", and narrow down your question:

- Does it always run slow, or just at boot/minutes at a time/only after a while/etc.
- Do programs open slowly, but seem to run fine after opening or vice-versa?
- Did windows 10 run fine before changing the boot type?
- Add the Version and OS build numbers from `Settings` > `About my PC`
- Does it run hot?
- Is windows 10 installed to an ssd (and/or win 8.1)
- Check your power/performance settings.
- Check your cpu base speed (in task manager > performance tab).

Anecdotally, I had an issue with a similar latitude model (5540) on an older build of win10 where it wasn't reading the cpu temperatures correctly and would throttle itself to <1.0 GHz.